# LokiJS: Simple find query returns wrong result

Tags: javascript, in-memory-database, lokijs, nosql

In LokiJS I try a very simple query (which I assume is AND):

```
var dbRes = recsCol.find({'format':format, 'cardId':-1});
```

after inserting some data with

```
recsCol.insert({format:format, cardId:id, recCardId:key, amount:item[key]});
```

that doesn't contain a cardId of -1.

The query still yields results. Is this expected behaviour? If so, how can I make the fields match exactly so that I won't get a result in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do an AND in LokiJS, no problem:

```
var dbRes = recsCol.find({'$and': [{'format':format}, {'cardId':-1}]});
```

I recommend using find for one-off queries. If the query occurs multiple times on resultsets that may change then definitely use a view.

Comment: This will do the same thing. Each field needs to be in its own query object for it to be an AND.

Comment: @AlexKinnee you are right, some oversight for me seeing as i wrote LokiJS ! I updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: @AlexKinnee i also upvoted your answer as it was actually the correct one, but my one was marked as correct so i didn't want people to get misinformed.

Answer (score 4):

By default, all fields in a query object are treated as an OR. To make it an AND you will need to change your query syntax to the following:

```
recsCol.find({
    $and: [
        {'format':format},
        {'cardId':-1}
    ]
});
```